# Reparameterized Surface Changes First Fundamental Form

Tags: differential-geometry

Suppose $q(r, \theta)$ is a parameterized surface with first fundamental form given as a matrix as

$\begin{bmatrix}
g_{rr} & g_{r\theta} \\
g_{r\theta} & g_{\theta\theta}
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 
0 & r^2
\end{bmatrix}$

I am asked to show that it is possible to reparameterize $q$ in terms of two other parameters $u,v$ so that we can instead write:

$\begin{bmatrix}
g_{uu} & g_{uv} \\
g_{uv} & g_{vv}
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$.

Now I know how to compute the first fundamental form. What I don't know is how to work out what to write for $u$ and $v$. Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposed that you define
$$
h(r, \theta) = q(r, \frac{\theta}{r}).
$$
Now $h_{\theta\theta}$ becomes 1, right? What about the other entries of the form? 
Doing substitution tricks like this can often help to "fix up" the first fundamental form, at least locally. (Obviously this is useless at $r = 0$, but your first parameterization is invalid there to, so it's probably OK.)

I just realized that in this context, it's not clear what $u$ and $v$ are. I should have written
$$
h(u, v) = q(u, \frac{v}{u}).
$$

Comment: And the first parameterization is invalid at $r=0$ because that implies $\frac{\partial q}{\partial \theta} =0$, which is impossible, yes?

Comment: Yes -- the first fundamental form must have nonzero determinant for the parameterization to be one that's suitable for doing the rest of the differential geometry calculations. (We often divide by $\det g$). Thus $(u, v) \mapsto (u^3, v^3, 0)$ is an invalid parameterization of the $xy$-plane in 3-space, even though it's a bijection and differentiable.